# Validation for input , don't accept spaces from first and last

Tags: php

I would like to put a validation on input, 
 Do not accept spaces from first and last.
 It accept if there are spaces from the middle.

`Example: 
  " Jordan" dont accept
  "Emily " dont accept
  "Michael Jackson" accept.`

Help me guys.
Thank you.

Comment: Post the code of what you've tried till now.

Comment: You are using jquery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of native PHP functions that `trim`s the strings from any character and the white space as default:

`trim()` — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string
`ltrim()` - Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning of a string
`rtrim()` - Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the end of a string

So in your case it would be enough to use:

```
$name = trim($name);
```

So you can accept all strings and just `trim` them on serverside before usage.

See it live: **https://eval.in/931367**

```
<?php
var_dump(trim(' Jordan'));
var_dump(trim('Emily '));
var_dump(trim('Michael Jackson'));
```

returns

> string(6) "Jordan"
>   string(5) "Emily"
>   string(15) "Michael Jackson"

Comment: @zxKazumaxz in cas of any clarification needed just comment this post.

Answer (score 0):

Best way of validating page is using [jquery validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

```js
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    Email: {
        required: {
            depends:function(){
                $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
                return true;
            }
        },
        email: true
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
<label for="field">Required: </label>
<input type="text" class="left" id="field" name="Email">
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Validate!">
</form>
```